# Add listener when dialog is closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In this fiddle a dialog is displayed :

http://jsfiddle.net/6M5g4/

Fiddle code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Is there a listener I can add which fires if the 'X' button is clicked or if the dialog is closed by a button on the dialog?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#events Yes.

Comment: You should really familiarize yourself with the documentation of elements that you are using.  The world doesn't need another copy/paste developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use the dialog's [close event](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close).

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        close: function (event, ui) {
            alert('Closed!')
        }
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6M5g4/1/)**